# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat, weblogic, eclipselink

I am trying to deploy my application on Tomcat 9 and my application is using eclipselink as a JPA provider. My application is running fine on WebLogic 12 server but after deploying my application on Tomcat 9 it is giving following exception

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
>   cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection    at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:480)
>     at
>   com.temp.request.dao.hybrid.PartyRequestSearchDAOImpl.retrieveRequestsByFilter(PartyRequestSearchDAOImpl.java:543)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
>     at
>   com.temp.request.util.aspect.TraceLogger.logMethodEntryAndExit(TraceLogger.java:36)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:643)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:632)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
>     at
>   com.temp.request.util.aspect.ExecutionTimeLogger.logMethodExecutionTime(ExecutionTimeLogger.java:37)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:643)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:632)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.retrieveRequestsByFilter(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
>   cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

I have already included accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" in my server.xml

My server.xml is as follows

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="jdbc/DS_RW" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               username="user1" password="pass123" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@temp.com:1545/service01"
               accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" />  

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Whether Tomcat 9 supports Eclipselnik as a JPA provider? If not is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the Oracle9Platform target database platform, which relies on the native Oracle connection but the connection pool you are using is wrapping the connection. EclipseLink uses a ServerPlatform implementation to allow server specific code to unwrap the connection, but there isn't an implementation for Tomcat, so it is defaulting to using the NoServerPlatform which just hands back the connection.

To get this to work and use the Oracle specific database functionality on Tomcat, you will need to create a ServerPlatform implementation similar to https://github.com/ftahmed/eclipselink-server-platform-tomcat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/tomcat/TomcatPlatform.java
This code then uses the base class to call `connection.getMetaData().getConnection();` on the connection.  If this doesn't work, you will have to implement your own unwrap method to access the underlying OracleConnection from your proxy.

You then specify the target server platform class you wish to use via the "eclipselink.target-server" persistence property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="yourPackage.yourClass"/>
```